# Nodejs: How to reject https posts based on headers

Tags: node.js

In a node.js server that accepts HTTPS post requests that are typically pretty large (a few MBs) we want to be able to start processing the requests before the entire thing is accepted by the server.

For example, if a request with a big fat body arrives, we want to look at its path and based on it decide whether to terminate/reject it, without having to wait for the entire request to arrive (and pay IO cost of receiving that fat body).

Comment: Can't you check for request headers in `createServer` callback and do something like `request.pause(); if (request.url condition) { response.end(); return; } request.resume();`?

Comment: You mean in the `requestListener` that I pass wot `createServer`? That'll work if indeed both conditions hold: 1) all headers have been received and 2) it's not too late (i.e. the body hasn't been received yet). The documentation isn't clear about whether or not these conditions hold.

Comment: Have you look into this? https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable (This is what Express.js uses to parse the body of requests)

Comment: node-formidable seems to be one layer above what's needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the the Connect Limit middleware:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/limit.js

or, implement your own solution in a similar way by checking req.headers[content-length], etc..

Comment: Quick note: Checking req.headers[content-length] can be a terrible idea, it's fairly easy to manipulate it with a simple "curl -H 'Content-length: 1' --data 'thisisnot=one' http://your.host".

Comment: Question is whether req.headers is accessible before the request body is received.

Comment: Node HTTP will parse the request into headers and body, but does not parse the actual headers and body. You may want to consider a library like Mikeals' Request which makes it easy to use the Node Stream API. You'd then use an EventEmitter, wait for the 'data' event handle accordingly once the headers are received.

https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/434

Answer (score 0):

Based on experimentation, it seems that Node.js only fires the `request` event after parsing the HTTP headers. Meaning there's a chance to examine the headers before we even start listening for the `data` event.

Thus the solution seems to be to check the headers before reading any data, and potentially rejecting the request at that point. If we don't reject at that point, we start accumulating the data buffers as they arrive and if they exceed the limit (and thus conflict with the reported content length) we have another chance to reject the request right there by calling `response.end()`.